# BigQuery REGEXP_REPLACE & CAST String AS DATETIME

Tags: sql, datetime, replace, google-bigquery

Currently, the event_timestamp is a string "06/06/2022 17:31:29" Because of the "/", CAST won't work. So i need to first replace "/" with "-" and then cast.

Here's what I have, but I am getting an error.

```html
  REGEXP_REPLACE(event_timestamp, r"/", "-") AS CAST(event_timestamp AS DATETIME) as event_timestamp
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `parse_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %T', event_timestamp)` instead

Comment: Thank you. I should have provided more details. This is part of a union. The other data source event_timestamp format is "2022-05-17 09:01:00 UTC". So i am CAST(event_timestamp AS DATETIME) AS event_timestamp. With your suggestion I get "2022-11-02T09:03:54" however, that doesn't align with the CAST. I'd like to end up with "2022-05-17 09:01:00".